# How to Get the Three Nearest Points to an Object (different layer)?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, spatial-database, buffer, clip

I have two point shapefiles and I want for each point in the 1st shapefile to get the 3 closest (based on air distance) points from the 2nd shapefile.

If possible, it would be great to have each of the three as a new column (as if a variable name) and the value is the distance.

Thanks a lot!

M

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Here's some [rather old VBA code](http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=992&t=83072#225728).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how many points you have and your extensions, you can generate a near table.
You can use this parameter to limit it to the nearest three:

closest_count (Optional)  Dialog Reference
Find only the specified number of closest features. This parameter will not be used if the Find only closest feature option is checked.